# Problem using pgfplots and externalize

Tags: pgfplots, xetex, texstudio, tikz-external

Having trouble using the externalize feature of pgfplots.

Here is my MWE, from overleafs pgfplots guide so I figure it should work.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}

% We will externalize the figures
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
    
    First example is 2D and 3D math expressions plotted side-by-side.
    
    %Here begins the 2D plot
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot[color=red]{exp(x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %Here ends the 2D plot
    \hskip 5pt
    %Here begins the 3D plot
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot3[
            surf,
            ]
            {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %Here ends the 3D plot
    
\end{document}
```

Using texlive with an updated tikz I get the following error `Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -interact`

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I just tried with a local Miktex-Installation which seems to work fine.

Comment: Did Gunter's answer solve your problem or do you need further assistance?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the option `-shell-escape` to the call of `pdflatex` to allow for rendering of the externalized figures.

See section 3.2.6 in the [pgfplots manual](https://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf). Alternatively see section 52.4 in the [tikz and pgf manual](https://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).